# Get-ChildItem ignoring "$Recycle.bin" folder?

Tags: powershell

I've started using a powershell script to clean all files that are older than 30 days in the roaming profiles of all our users.

This is the script I use:

```
$oldTime = [int]30 #30 days
foreach ($path in Get-Content "pathList.txt") {
    Write-Host "Trying to delete files older than $oldTime days, in the folder $path" -ForegroundColor Green
    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Verbose | WHERE {($_.CreationTime -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(-$oldTime))} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
}
```

Here is the Pathlist.txt

```
\\FS001\RDS_FolderRedirection$\*\Downloads
\\FS001\RDS_FolderRedirection$\*\Downloads\$RECYCLE.BIN
```

For some reason the script ignores the `$RECYCLE.BIN` folder.. am I missing something here?

Comment: try the switch hidden for get-childitem

Comment: Try the `-Force` param `Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Verbose -Force` the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) explains it's use: "Allows the cmdlet to get items that cannot otherwise not be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files."

Comment: Thank you James C! I was a little thrown off as I already stated the -Force param with Remove-Item. This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `-Force` param with `Get-ChildItem`, the Documentation explains it's use as:

> Allows the cmdlet to get items that cannot otherwise not be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files.

It would be used in your code like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Verbose -Force
```